# Using filtered rows as part of DBContext with derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

I want to use class inheritance for filtering rows in database which is not absolutery normal and relational. There is table `entities` mapped to model `Entity` via EF Core:

```
[Table("entities")]
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

`Type` is some string that can be "A" or "B" e.g.

I want to specify class `EntityA : Entity` for entities with type A and accordingly for B:

```
public class EntityA : Entity
{
    // some unique A properties
}

public class EntityB : Entity
{
    // some unique B properties
}
```

Basically my DBContext looks like

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Can I defined `EntitiesA` and `EntitiesB` in my `DBContext` using filtering by Type?

I wanted to write it at least in stupid way:

```
public List<EntityA> EntitiesA
{
    get
    {
        return Entity.Where(x => x.Type == "A").ToList();
    }
}
```

But there is class casting problem (because code returns List, not List) and also it's not like ORM-style solution, EntitiesA is not DBSet, load query automatically and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found, It's called `Discriminator` in EF Core, those who interested can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to bring EntitiesA and EntitiesB to DBContext. Because basically, it contains some of the application domain knowledge (Business Layer), which should be completely decoupled with your DBContext (Data Access Layer).

I suggest to have a EntityLoader in Business Layer which is responsible for loading Entities from DB and return list of EntityA or B.

Regarding the class casting problem, you can fix the compile error with

```
return Entity.Where(x => x.Type == "A").Select(x => (EntityA)x).ToList();
```

However, you will get a runtime error since the Entity type is less specific than the EntityA type. Which mean you need to convert like this

```
return Entity.Where(x => x.Type == "A").Select(x => new EntityA(....)).ToList();
```

Comment: It is actually datalayer logic and not business logic. Because it's external database created for cms which has no similar with asp application. For data layer in asp application it's better to understand rows from this table as different models which are supposed to be different tables if we start from scratch for our asp app.

Comment: In EF Core Discriminator, you still need a DB table for EntityA and a DB table for EntityB. But in your question, you say that there is only 1 table for Entity. I may misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, it's about common table. You can open link from my answer - there is even screenshot with one table generating different entities